How can I use log4cxx AsyncAppender with RollingFileAppender?
My Linux C++ application uses log4cxx and the RollingFileAppender. During normal application operations we sometimes see a few mSec program pause. This seems to occur at the same time as the time on the first log line in a log file. I'm guessing the file "rolling" mechanism momentarily slows the server and application.
I think that if I use the AsyncAppender together with RollingFileAppender this will solve this problem. How do I do that?
My current relevant .hpp code is:
log4cxx::RollingFileAppenderPtr  appender;
log4cxx::TTCCLayoutPtr           layout;

My current relevant .cpp code is:
    void FileLogger::initialize() {
    layout = new TTCCLayout("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    layout->setThreadPrinting(false);
    layout->setCategoryPrefixing(false);
    appender = new RollingFileAppender(layout, fileName);
    appender->setName("fileLogger");
    appender->setMaximumFileSize(maxSize);
    appender->setMaxBackupIndex(maxFiles);
    setLogLevel();
    BasicConfigurator::configure(appender);
    logInfo("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
    logInfo("Logging initialized");
    }
 

I read lots of documentation. I saw mention of using two appenders together. But I don't know how to do that. What is the syntax?
